# Python: Time complexity of .isAlpha

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity

So I can't find the official documentation on how the isalpha method was written (of the string module), but I imagine the algorithm used would be:

---

1). Convert char in question to int.
2). Compare it to the larger alpha-ascii values (i.e. 90 or 122) to see if it less than or equal to these values.
3). Compare it to the larger alpha-ascii values, i.e. 55 or 97 depending on the upper bound used (if only less than 90 use 55...), to see if it greater than or equal to these values.

---

Am I correct in this assessment of the isalpha method or is it something different altogether? If so does it have a complexity of O(3)?

Comment: Time complexity tells you how the time taken by  the method scales _with the size of the input_. `O(3)` (or more commonly `O(1)`) implies that the method runs in constant time regardless of the size of the input. Given this information, what do you think the time complexity of the function is? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3255/843953)

Comment: Python is open source, so you can go look at the implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/bytes_methods.c#L43

Comment: @thebjorn is the link that you provided Python in C or C++? Please keep in mind I would consider myself a beginner programmer.

Comment: @JoshuaFolh, sorry, you had "familiar with..." on your profile so I just assumed. The link goes to the Python implementation of isAlpha, it may not be suitable/useful for beginner programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python handles text as unicode. As such, what character is alphabetic and what is not depends on the character unicode category, enconpassing all characters defined on the unicode version compiled along with Python. That is tens of hundreds of characters, and hundreds of scripts, etc... each with their own alphabetic ranges. Although it all boils down to numeric ranges of the codepoints that could be compared using other algorithms, it is almost certain all characters are iterated, and the character unicode category is checked. If you want the complexity, it is then `O(n)` .

(Actually, it would have been O(n) on your example as well, since all characters have to be checked. For a single character, Python uses a dict, or dict-like table to get from the character to its category infomation, and that is O(1))

Comment: Yes, O(N) on the size of the input string, to be precise (the OP seems to be assuming `.isalpha` on a length-1 string)

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand:
@juanpa.arrivillaga what do you mean "the OP seems to be assuming..."? you realize I am talking about the complexity of a single character, no?

and jsbueno I am confused as to whether it is O(1) or O(n) because your answer says both, and don't even know what n of O(n) would look like.

Comment: The complexity for a single character is O(1) . O(n)  means that it is linearly proportional to "n", which, in the context, would be the length of the string you are checking.

Comment: @jsbueno okay so O(n) would be applicable if iterating through a string of characters, whereas O(1) is for something like "c='a' c.isalpha()"  ?